# Add line to 3d column chart in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm using highcharts to make some data charts in a project and at the moment, doing it in 2D it works perfectly:

[Chart working in 2D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9sHD.png)

This is a set of percentages for each month, with a red line that indicates the goal % to easily visualize whether or not a set of data is over or under that percentage.

The problem is now that I'm trying to make it 3D to give it more of a 'pop', I include the 3D library and enable it but the graph turns out like this:

[Chart NOT working in 3D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHUpb.png)

Even though the bars display as intended, the line messes up and is nowhere near where it should be.

I've tried changing from spline to scatter with no success. Does anyone have any idea as to how I can fix this, or maybe a different way to present this "goal" so that you can easily see which bars are over or under it.

Thanks in advance!

PS: This is the JSON for the Highcharts options I'm using for 3D:

```html
{
  "chart": {
    "options3d": {
      "enabled": true,
      "alpha": 0,
      "beta": 0,
      "depth": 20
    }
  },
  "title": {
    "text": "Title"
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "categories": [
      "a",
      "b"
    ],
    "crosshair": false,
    "gridLineWidth": 1,
    "min": 0,
    "max": 1
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "floor": 98,
    "ceiling": 100,
    "title": {
      "text": "%"
    }
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "column": {
      "pointPadding": 0.2,
      "borderWidth": 0
    },
    "scatter": {
      "width": 10,
      "height": 100,
      "depth": 10
    }
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "name": "ENERO",
      "type": "column",
      "data": [
        99.8,
        99.77
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "FEBRERO",
      "type": "column",
      "data": [
        100,
        99.83
      ]
    },
    {
      "lineWidth": 1,
      "name": "Meta (99.8%)",
      "type": "scatter",
      "color": "#FF0000",
      "marker": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "legend": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "data": [
        [
          -1,
          99.8,
          2
        ],
        [
          2,
          99.8,
          2
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The line chart is not fully supported in 3d, but if your goal is draw a line only, you can use plotLines. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v66zt28y/

Comment: I have reported this behaviour as a bug. See the github issue tracker - https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6972

Comment: @SebastianBochan thanks so much for this. If you want to post it as a solution so I can pick it, do so as I think it's the closest I'm gonna get to solving my problem (and it works well enough for what I need). So again, thanks.

Comment: @morganfree Thanks for that. I'll keep an eye on it and see if someone replies.

Comment: @JoséColina i did it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line chart is not fully supported in 3d, but if your goal is draw a line only, you can use plotLines.

```
"yAxis": {
    "plotLines":[{
       "value": 99.5,
       "width": 2,
       "color": 'red'
    }],
    "floor": 98,
    "ceiling": 100,
    "title": {
      "text": "%"
    }
},
```

Demo:

- http://jsfiddle.net/v66zt28y